# Android - best way to store hash data (rooted device)

Tags: android, kotlin, security

I'm making an app which include storing password created by user.

Obviously password will be hashed (e.g PBKDF2) and there is my problem:

**Where to store hash?**

I gave up the idea of storing it in SharedPreferences or android database because it could be achieved in rooted device.

To summarize: I know that hashing is a clever way to secure our data but I wonder is there any way to secure hash?

Comment: Usually one stores the hash on the server side. Why do you consider storing the hash on the client side?

Comment: If the password is coming from the user, what is your concern over rooted devices? Most rooted devices are rooted by the user, and the user already knows the user's password.

Comment: @MarekPuchalski I'm working on app which require to create a new password by user. I do not want to store it on server (as it requires connection). App is for learning purposes and I wonder is there any way to securely store hash in device

Comment: @CommonsWare I got your point. I keep wondering and what if other app gain root permissions and achieve a hash?
My question is: are we able store any data locally to be sure that anyone get access to it?

Comment: This might be a good use case for the relatively new security library in Jetpack: https://developer.android.com/topic/security/data